# Connection refused in Django_beanstalkd

Tags: python, django, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

I'm very stuck with this. I have an app in Django that uses beanstalkd to establish a connection with vlcserver. Vlcserver captures video from an rtsp stream of an IP camera, and after that, that video is transcoded to a h264 format. The problem comes when I try to establish a connection with the beanstalkd server.

```
beanstalkc.Connection('127.0.0.1', 11300)
```

When this instruction is executed, it appears an exception: [errno 111] Connection refused. The port is open in the firewall. I don't know what I can do to fix this. Help please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Job #1, make sure the daemon is also running (pgrep -lf beanstalkd) and then "telnet 127.0.0.1 11300". What does VLCserver have to do with it though?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your beanstalkd instance is listening on a particular interface (-l command line parameter). If this is the case, then you need to either remove the parameter or set it to be -l 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces.